# I dont use graph mdb.js on ajax script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**I try the include js files on script like that**
  *This way is true ?*

```
var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');  
jQueryScript.setAttribute('src','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(jQueryScript);'
```

**But It doesn't work and I cant show graph and I cant use ajax api data for myPieChart also I try** `myPieChart.datasets.data[0] = min;` **In this way correct ?**

```
// JQuery 
var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');  
jQueryScript.setAttribute('src','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(jQueryScript);
// MDB core JavaScript 
var mdbScript = document.createElement('script');  
mdbScript.setAttribute('src','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.10.1/js/mdb.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(mdbScript);

var bootstrapToolTip = document.createElement('script');  
bootstrapToolTip.setAttribute('src','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(bootstrapToolTip);

var bootstrapCore = document.createElement('script');  
bootstrapCore.setAttribute('src','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(bootstrapCore);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitForecast").click(function(){
        return getForecast();
    });

    });

    var min,max,pressure,humidity,speed,deg;

    function getForecast(){
        var city = $("#city").val();
        var days = $("#days").val();

        if(city != '' && days != ''){

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=' + city + "&units=metric" + "&cnt=" + days + "&APPID=c10bb3bd22f90d636baa008b1529ee25",
                type: "GET",
                async:false,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data){

                    for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++){

                        min += data.list[i].temp.min
                        max += data.list[i].temp.max
                        pressure += data.list[i].pressure
                        humidity += data.list[i].humidity
                        speed += data.list[i].speed
                        deg += data.list[i].deg
                    }

                    $("#city").val('');
                    $("#days").val('')

                }

            });

        }else{
            $("#error").html("<div class='alert alert-danger' id='errorCity'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>City field cannot be empty</div>");
        }

    }

//pie
var ctxP = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext('2d');
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctxP, {
type: 'pie',
data: {
labels: ["Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Grey", "Dark Grey"],
datasets: [{
data: [300, 50, 100, 40, 120],
backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360"],
hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#A8B3C5", "#616774"]
}]
},
options: {
responsive: true
}
});

myPieChart.datasets.data[0] = min;
myPieChart.datasets.data[1] = max;
myPieChart.datasets.data[2] = pressure;
myPieChart.datasets.data[3] = humidity;
myPieChart.datasets.data[4] = speed;
```

**I take those two erors i dont solve that**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej0aS.png)

I hope find a solution

Comment: Copying the errors as text is more useful than posting as a link to an image :)

Comment: Sorry my mistake eror here : Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

Comment: Your script tags might not be loading etc, and this is a pretty bad way of adding scripts to a document (hard for the browser to predict, etc)- try adding them to the HTML of your page

Comment: I know actually but I have to take the ajax data to push the chart If I use on HTML I did not reach and I did not assign a variable Should I use nodeJS ?